# Docker for SQL Server 2012 Container support

Tags: docker, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

We use Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012, and I'm looking for a way to provision instances for QA.   I've seen Docker on Linux, and heard about MS docker support for Server 2016, but need a solution for SQL Server 2012.   We would favor Docker based solution, as it aligns with Microsoft direction.

Comment: No way, you need server 2016, and in 2012, docker containers did not exist, so how server 2012 would deal with containers?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [Windocks](http://windocks.com/) has found a way to accomplish it, been trying to find out how to reproduce it as well but looks like its solution with a bunch of moving parts.

Comment: There's a downloadable free Community edition of Windocks now with a self extracting installer. Its easier to make that work and its available [here](http://windocks.com/lps/communityedition)

Comment: I'm involve in WinDocks.   It's a simple self-extracting installer, and adds container support for all editions of Windows 8, 10, Server 2012, and Server 2016.   The containers are essentially SQL Server named instances provisioned with container based API and tooling . . . it's actually pretty simple, and proving popular for Dev/QA use.

Answer (score -5):

No way, you need Server 2016, and in 2012, docker containers did not exist, so how Server 2012 would deal with containers?

Comment: You can still install old software in containers, so if someone creates an image that contains SQL Server 2012, or even older, that would work. For example, there's also an image for [CentOS 5](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/)

Comment: and SQL Server for Linux is coming https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/sql-server-on-linux.aspx